# OSX Homebrew error: uninitialized constant MACOS

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've searched around a bit and can't seem to find any record of anyone else with this problem.

Whenever I try to run

```
$ brew update
```

I am rewarded with

```
/usr/local/bin/brew:34: uninitialized constant MACOS (NameError)
```

This isn't my machine and I normally develop on Linux systems so this is all a bit odd to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Please tell me if there is any additional info I should provide.  Again, I'm not used to homebrew or OSX.

**EDIT**
at the request of JameA

```
xiao:~ patrick$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew:34: uninitialized constant MACOS (NameError)
xiao:~ patrick$ brew --config
/usr/local/bin/brew:34: uninitialized constant MACOS (NameError)
```

...Not sure I like this whole "here, use this macbook for the project, it works better" thing...

Comment: What is on line 34 of that file (/usr/local/bin/brew)? My line 34 doesn't have the constant MACOS but it does have MACOS_VERSION. But anyway, looking at the code would help know what's going on.

Comment: what does 'which brew' gives you?

Comment: @user1087981
`34  if MACOS and MACOS_VERSION < 10.5`
@Usman
`$ which brew`
`/usr/local/bin/brew`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MACOS` constant is set in `globals.rb`.  It seems like you may have a borked installation of Homebrew.

Check the output of `brew doctor` for any suggestions.

If that doesn't help please update with the results of `brew --config`.

If all else fails you may want to try re-installing Homebrew.

---

**UPDATE:**

Since this was a previous user's machine make sure your user is the owner of */usr/local* and everything within.  Fix it with `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`.

Comment: Updated the question with the results.  I'm leaning towards the borked install though, this was someone else's dev system before I got it and still has accounts and software on it from the last project.  I need to talk my boss into letting me do a fresh install.  I know for a fact that some stuff is broken on it, it crashes when you try and update the system.

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure the root cause of this is a failed upgrade attempt to Homebrew 0.9.5 from a much earlier version.  Basically, if you run `brew update` as opposed to `sudo brew update` a portion of files are updated, while others are not.  Here's what worked for me:

1. Edit `/usr/local/bin/brew` (it's just a Ruby file, not a compiled binary, so any text editor will do).  You'll find a block like:

   ```
   if MACOS and MACOS_VERSION < 10.5
     abort <<-EOABORT.undent
       Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
       https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew
     EOABORT
   end
   ```

   Comment this out.  Even if you don't know Ruby, you can probably intuit what this is doing—it's checking to see if you have a current version of OSX.  Assuming that you *do* in fact have this version, this sanity check isn't necessary.  Brew is still broken, but at least now it will load far enough to give error messages.
2. Run `sudo brew update`, *spoiler alert*: it fails, but this time with a meaningful error message:

   ```
    $ brew update
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    [giant list of files here]
   ```

   Well, today I learned that `brew update` is just a wrapper for `git pull` because anyone who has worked with git knows that error message.  We can fix this too.
3. Switch into the homebrew git repository with `cd /usr/local` and give the command `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`.
   [This piece found here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues#wiki-brew-update-complains-about-untracked-working-tree-files).
4. Give the command `sudo brew update`.  Homebrew should now update successfully and work properly!

Once the system is working again, you can actually kind of see why an error like this would have occurred.  For one, `usr/local/bin/brew` has been [completely rewriten](https://gist.github.com/MKorostoff/8652464) and isn't even Ruby anymore, and most of its configuration has been moved into `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb` which no longer uses the constants `MACOS` or `MACOS_VERSION` constants, as they have been replaced by the more object oriented `OS.mac` and `MacOS.version`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, when I Killed an install mid-way with Ctrl-D.
Post that whenever I tried installing anything it gave the following error

```
uninitialized constant Homebrew::CLI::Parser::ARGV_WITHOUT_MONKEY_PATCHING
```

As a fix, I went to the directory I had where homebrew was installed, and reset the HEAD.

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew
git status 
git checkout .
```

And then it started working magically. 
[image: Resetting Homebrew to master]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with a "borked" installation of brew. I removed the small 5 line block of code in the /usr/local/bin/brew script starting with the MACOS line. That did the trick to allow me to uninstall and eventually reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt Korostoff's answer.
On point 3 (resetting the repo), for recent version of Homebrew, the repo is no longer `/usr/local`, do `cd "$(brew --repo)"` instead.