# OS X 10.9.1 /usr/local/bin/brew:38: uninitialized constant MACOS (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

My question is really simmilar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173458/osx-homebrew-error-uninitialized-constant-macos), but it answer doesn't suit me.

I get the same error (`/usr/local/bin/brew:38: uninitialized constant MACOS (NameError)`) no matter what I do.

I've tried this and got the same error with them all:

```
$ brew doctor

$ brew --config

$ brew install ant
```

Even with this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, at the end, removing all brew files and installing them again solved all problems.