# Homebrew OSX 10.9.3: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant OS (NameError)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I think I have a borked installation of Homebrew. Whenever I type any of the brew commands, I get an uninitialized constant OS error.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ aramu$ brew update
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant OS (NameError)
MacBook-Pro-2:~ aramu$ brew doctor
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant OS (NameError)
MacBook-Pro-2:~ aramu$ brew --config
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant OS (NameError)
```

I looked through the solution for a similar question ([OSX Homebrew error: uninitialized constant MACOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173458/osx-homebrew-error-uninitialized-constant-macos)) which suggested that my user be the owner of /usr/local/ and everything within. It still doesn't work for me.

Note: The machine had been previously used and on receiving it, I have created a new user for me with admin privileges.

The following is how the permissions are set for that folder now:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ aramu$ ls -lrth /usr/local/
total 80
drwxrwxr-x   5 aramu  admin   170B Oct 22  2013 libexec
drwxrwxr-x   4 aramu  admin   136B Jan 28 14:20 var
drwxrwxr-x  10 aramu  admin   340B Jan 28 14:20 share
drwxr-xr-x   5 aramu  admin   170B Jan 28 14:20 opt
drwxr-xr-x   5 aramu  admin   170B Jan 28 14:20 man
drwxrwxr-x  24 aramu  admin   816B Jan 28 14:20 lib
drwxrwxr-x  29 aramu  admin   986B Jan 28 14:20 include
drwxrwxr-x   4 aramu  admin   136B Jan 28 14:20 etc
-rw-r--r--   1 aramu  admin    23K Jun  4 16:14 SUPPORTERS.md
-rw-r--r--   1 aramu  admin   1.8K Jun  4 16:14 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 aramu  admin   1.2K Jun  4 16:14 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 aramu  admin   687B Jun  4 16:14 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--   1 aramu  admin   3.1K Jun  4 16:14 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
drwxrwxr-x  31 aramu  admin   1.0K Jul 10 14:16 bin
drwxrwxr-x   9 aramu  admin   306B Jul 10 14:22 Library
MacBook-Pro-2:~ aramu$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for solving this was to completely uninstall Homebrew from the system and start from scratch.

I used the code provided in [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223) to uninstall homebrew.