# OSX homebrew error when install gdb: ''Uninitialized constant Homebrew::FormulaClassUnavailableError"

Tags: macos, gdb, homebrew

I am having problems installing gdb on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

I ran `brew install homebrew/dupes/gdb` in terminal,
and got

```
Error: uninitialized constant Homebrew::FormulaClassUnavailableError
Please report this bug:
    https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:151:in `rescue in install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:82:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:84:in `<main>'
```

What does that mean and how to fix that? 
Could anyone please help me.

**Edit:**
After run `brew doctor` I got these:

```
Warning: /usr/local/bin isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local/bin
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Suspicious git origin remote found.

With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't pull updates from
the main repository. The current git origin is:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

Unless you have compelling reasons, consider setting the
origin remote to point at the main repository, located at:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
```

Is it the cause of the homebrew or any other reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX Homebrew error: uninitialized constant MACOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173458/osx-homebrew-error-uninitialized-constant-macos)

Comment: @jwpfox I have checked that question but I don't think it helps.

Comment: Nice edit! you have improved the question a lot with those additions. Did any of the suggestions supplied by Homebrew provide any happiness?

Comment: @jwpfox I think not, and I don't really understand the connections between those suggestions and my problem.

Comment: Do you have MacPorts or Fink installed? They tend to play badly with Homebrew. I had to delete both to get Homebrew to install on my machine. If not that then any of the other suggestions? I know this is not very helpful but when this goes wrong it is generally a lot of trial and error in the particular machine to try and get things going again. I don't think there is likely to be a simple, general, answer, sadly.

Comment: @jwpfox I installed MacPorts because I tried to follow an answer on SO to install gdb on mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162757/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-in-mac-osx-el-capitan but it doesn't work.